# access mySql database on file basis

Tags: mysql, file, backup

Okay, heres a easy one for all you mysql folks out there:

Our Win 2003 server crashed last night (durring installing of windows updates). We were able to restore old data from backup, but we miss 22 hours of data. We cannot start windows and therefore not access the data through mySql admin which is the program I use normally to make backup. We have however been able to copy all data to external harddisk.

How do I access these data usning MySql Query browser and MySql Administrator tool?

Comment: You can *try* to copy the data in the datadir in another clean/unused install (with MySQL off of course), start MySQL, and pray it works. This is however not guaranteed to work.

Comment: What @Wrikken says is probably the only way to do this - maybe worth putting as an answer? Be sure to make backups of the raw data files before starting a new mySQL server on them.

Comment: okay, got the files on my local setup now - will try ur suggestion

Comment: Okay, I got it working. Had to save the files in same folder as on the server and copy the .ini files from the server as well. How do I mark wrikkens comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't rate comments as an answer, saves a lot in the whole point-system :P (I did however later think of binlogs, and added that in combination with the previous comment as an answer about 3 hours ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't have binlogs enabled, or cannot be sure at which point your backup snapshot was made trying to get the datadir running in another server is about your only option. (Which for maximum possibility of recovery should be as much like the original as possible in MySQL version and other environmental data).
2. If you *do*  have active binlogs, look at [this manual](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/point_in_time_recovery.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please let me preface this by saying, I'm not a Windows administrator, so permissions issues are outside my expertise.

1. Setup a new machine running the same version of MySQL.
2. Create a new folder and copy your backup of mysql data to that folder, including the mysql database.
3. Edit your my.cnf file on the new machine to change the following:

`# set your data directory`

`datadir = c:\path\to\new\datadir`

`# just in case`

`skip-slave-start`

`# optional`

`skip-networking`

`# if this is an emergency and you need to go through password recovery`

`skip-grant-tables`

Restart MySQL and watch your error log for output. It should start up and you can simply sign in as 'root' with no password and do what you need to do to backup your data.